# npm-clipboardy does not work when I launch my Discord Bot in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js, clipboard

I get this error in my Heroku console :

```
Couldn't find the xsel binary and fallback didn't work. On Debian/Ubuntu you can install xsel with: sudo apt install xsel
```

**I made my discord bot and am trying to launch it in Heroku but the clipboardy does not seems to function . I used Windows 10,Node 14.18.3 and Clipboardy 2.3.0**

If have a solution or a alternate for clipboardy do help.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the clipboard module to do on a heroku server?

Comment: I am looking a alternative  @NullDev . I want it to copy text

Comment: Then just read text and save it somewhere. E.g. a file or a database.